# Is it possible show the feature attributes dialog when I add a feature in code?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, features, c++

I want to know if it is possible to make the feature attributes dialog in Qgis show up when I add a feature by code using:

`QgsVectorLayer::addFeature( tFeature )`

This is available when I add features using Qgis' digitizing tools but not when I add features by code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, This can be done by using : 

`QgisInterface::openFeatureForm ( QgsVectorLayer *vlayer, QgsFeature &f, bool updateFeatureOnly = false )`